Is there any way to provide custom categories?
I am trying to customize the widget. I have used the below code to enable categories, but have no idea how I show my own values:
Userback.widget_settings = {
  style: "circle",
  position: "sw",
  form_settings: {
      general: {
        display_priority: false,
        display_assignee: false,
        display_category:true,
      }
    }
};

All I see is the below:


I doubt .widget_settings will contains values. There is probably another property, or you need to assign values to an instance of the widget. You may need to provide more context/code.

@Mr.Polywhirl All I can provide you this doc url https://docs.userback.io/docs/prefill-fields#email-string-name-string-categories-string-priority-string

I found this in the docs:

Categories and Priority
categories: string
Define the categories that can be chosen in the feedback form.
Userback.categories = "Frontend,Backend,Database,UI";



This does not work. I already had checked it out

To all future visitors
The easiest way to do it is to go to your project settings, you would find a section to add and remove categories. Just add it and use Category section in widget settings to enable it

